# NHibernate combining two database tables into one object

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am using FluentNhibernate and i have a question about is. Is it possible two combine data from to different database tables into on entity? I have to work with an access database and an mssql datatbase and to work with both i think it is easier to combine. For example

Db table 1 
 - name
 - address
 - email

Db table 2
 - Selected
 - DateSelection

Is it possible to combine these two into on entity using Nhibernate

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fluent NHibernate - Map 2 tables to one class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881168/fluent-nhibernate-map-2-tables-to-one-class)

Answer (score 0):

No, NHibernate SessionFactory has only unique connection. if you need union two table from difference database, DB2 table 2 make view! in DB1